# How to select a drop down option based on text of a variable in python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

All, I'm just learning python as well as selenium. and i'm stuck on how to select from a dropdown menu based on a variable.

I am able to select it based on the Text within the dropdown menu. like below ...

```
CreateJob = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Create Activity')
time.sleep(5)
CreateJob.click()
time.sleep(5)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('worktype'))
print ("select.options")
time.sleep(3)
select.select_by_visible_text("THE ITEM I WANT") # orig working
```

However, what I need is the string "THE ITEM I WANT" to be defined by a variable so I only have to change it once in the code.

I have tried the following but no luck... Any idea's?

```
createjob1 = "THE ITEM I WANT"
#select.select_by_visible_text(.,'%s')]" % createjob1) # not working 
#select.select_by_visible_text('%s') % "createjob1" # not working
#select.select_by_visible_text('%s') % "createjob1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly pass variable `createjob1`  into `select_by_visible_text()` as below :

```
createjob1 = "THE ITEM I WANT"
select.select_by_visible_text(createjob1)
```